# Copy the values of some cells on the same sheet with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I've seen some discussions here on the subject, but I'm not able to solve my problem. I need to copy the values of some cells in the same sheet in excel. But when I run the following example, it only searches for the values in the first run and in the second it returns None. It just returns the values when I open the .xlsx file and save again. I'm on Ubuntu and xlwings doesn't work. If you are wondering why I created a new workbook is because when I save the file in the workbook in data_only=true mode, it removes all the formulas from the original file and as I said I only need to copy the values of some cells that contain the formula into other cells on the same sheet. Another detail is, I need to do other things in this worksheet so my code needs to create a workbook before copying these values and if I create a workbook before creating a new workbook in data_only=true mode it already returns None directly.

```
wb = load_workbook(path,data_only=True)
print(wb.worksheets[-1].cell(row=1,column=1).value)
print(wb.worksheets[-1].cell(row=2,column=1).value)
print(wb.worksheets[-1].cell(row=2,column=5).value)
wb.close()

workbook = load_workbook(path)
workbook.worksheets[-1].title = today
workbook.worksheets[-1].freeze_panes = 'B2'
workbook.save(file)
workbook.close()
```

I tried to use xlswings, I tried to copy the .value, I tried to run it only as a workbook in data_only = True mode (but as I said it removes all the formulas from the original file)...

Comment: It's not clear what your trying to do and your code does not reflect what your explanation says. Your code just opens a prints the values of cells A1, A2 and E2 from a worksheet then closes the wb, opens it again and sets the title of the worksheet and sets a freeze pane. If you are searching for some data to copy to a new wb, what data/criteria. Copying the data to another wb means you do need to create the wb and sheet and then select the cell you want to copy data to, then set its value to be the value of cell from another sheet or some other variable.